Is there a French noun equivalent for "twofer"?
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/twofer (mirror):

noun. Informal. A pair of (theater tickets, phonograph records, etc.) sold for, or approximately for, the price of one

Is there a French noun equivalent for "twofer"? I know one can say "deux pierres d'un coup" or "deux pour le prix d'un", but I wonder if there is a noun conveying a similar meaning.

The idiom is faire d'une pierre deux coups.

@jlliagre that makes more sense indeed :-)

Deux-pour-un could easily be made into a name; it'd be understood on 1st reading. Could you provide a French example with your problem? Else, answers are likely to be opinion-based.

I don't think there is a single word to convey that meaning.
You already provided deux pour le prix d'un which is probably the most common way to express it:


You might also read:

le deuxième gratuit.



Un acheté, un gratuit:



Un xxx acheté, un offert:



De nombreux exemples. Très bonne réponse.

In a translation of "twofer" in the context of discount prices of  consumer goods you would have to add a term which might often be "promotion" ("promotion de vente", "réclame", …).

une promotion « deux pour le prix d'un », j'ai vu des promotions « deux pour le prix d'un », ils offrent beaucoup de promotions « deux pour le prix d'un », …

Mise en place de promotions « Deux articles pour le prix d'un »

La critique qui va avec ce vote négatif ?  Est-elle si difficile à exprimer ?

imho commenting should be compulsory when downvoting. Otherwise nobody learns from it.

@FranckDernoncourt That is also my opinion, but I think certain people do not like this idea because having no oblgation makes it easy for them to put down whomever they do not like. It can be noticed that whether on ELU or FSE, serious user do explain their votes, and not a few tell you first what is wrong and vote later, which is even more constructive.

Be more proactive when a user continuously downvotes another user

@FranckDernoncourt I liked particularly one comment ("The number of downvotes on this completely valid question indicates that those engaging in the serial downvoting don't like attention being drawn to their toxic behavior. (For what it's worth, I'm upvoting...)"), and did as the user who wrote it.

Not my downvote but perhaps telling that we have to add a term seems exaggerated. Twofer is very terse and deux pour le prix d'un is always understood whatever the context. Réclame is very outdated, promotion de vente is a little outdated, even the most common promotion des ventes is going downward. Maybe offre spéciale or just promo are what is commonly used nowadays.
